# Not able to call API from jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, .net-core

My JS code:

```
var Id = 32456;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: RetrieveValue('href') + '/API/Delete',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + RetrieveValue("Token"),
    },
    data: '{"Id":' + Id+ '}',
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (response) { 
    },
    error: function (error) {                   
    }
});
```

My API code:

```
    [HttpPost("Delete/")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(long Id)
    {
    }
```

I am getting ID = 0, even though I have passed value.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: What happens when you call the api in postman or directly? [HttpPost("Delete/")] looks strange to me maybe try [HttpPost("Delete")]

Comment: Unrelated: Why aren't you using the HTTP method [`DELETE`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/DELETE) for this action?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Set id as query parameter:

```
url: RetriveValue('href') + '/API/Delete?Id=' + Id
```

Comment: OP is using `POST` as the HTTP method, unsure why resolving to a query string would fix the issue